# Merge Sort Algorithm Dilemma

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, mergesort

Consider a recursive implementation of Merge Sort which is used to sort an array of size `n`. The number of recursive calls made to Merge Sort is

either `O(n)` but not `Theta(n)`

or `Theta(n)`

or `O(n log n)` but not `Theta(n log n)`

or `Theta(n log n)`

PS : I am preparing for an exam and found this question, What I am thinking is that merge sort has a time complexity of `Theta(n log n)` but in that we have not considered the constants. So, it should be `O(n log n)` but not `Theta(n log n)`. But that is a wrong answer. What should be the correct answer and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Theta(n).

#### Detailed explanation.

The number of operations will be Theta(n log n), because at each level of recursion you will perform `Merge`s on the elements number summing up to `n`, and `Merge` has a complexity of Theta(n). That gives Theta(n) per level of recursion and you have log(n) levels which in total gives Theta(n log n).

**However, you are not supposed to give complexity for number of operations (which depends on `Theta(Merge)`), but number of `MergeSort` calls. This is different.**

user1990169 gives a very nice explanation how calculate the number of `MergeSort` calls. People seem to confuse it with number of operations, which is different.

Refer to the algorithm layout, where are `Merge` calls and where are `MergeSort` calls.

#### Why different answers are right or wrong?

A) O(n) but not Theta(n)

B) Theta(n)

C) O(n log n) but not Theta(n log n)

D) Theta(n log n)

Strictly speaking, in plain english. If Theta(f(x)) = Theta(g(x)) it means that f(x) is asymptotically not lower, and not greater that g(x). If f(x) belongs to O(g(x)) it "just" means f(x) will is asymptotically not greater than g(x).

The difference is: You can say that f(n) is O(n) as well as O(n^2) (it is not greater in both cases). But you cannot say f(n) is Theta(n^2). That being said, I don't know anyone with algorithmic background who would use BigO in such way, everyone uses it as a tight bound (like Theta).

So anything saying it is not Theta(n), or saying it is Theta( *something asymptotically else* ) is wrong (A and D). B is right.

C is "debatable". Technically I would say it's right too. Because n is asymptotically smaller or equal to n log n (Big O formal definition), also it is not equal to n log n (Theta formal definition). You can refer to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Use_in_computer_science) they use similar example.

Answer (score 4):

At each level of recursion, you call two instances of Mergesort. Also, the recursion depth is `log(n)`

```
Hence the number of calls to MergeSort = 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2^(logn)
                                       = 2 * ( 2^logn - 1 ) / (2 - 1)
                                       = 2 * (n - 1 )
                                       = Theta(N)
```

So the number of calls is `Theta(N)`. However, the overall time complexity of the algorithm is `Theta(NlogN)` because at each depth in the recursion, you perform `Theta(N)` steps for merging the sorted arrays and the total depth of the recursion tree is `Theta(logN)`.

Comment: So the number of recursive calls that we are making is Theta(nlogn) ?

Comment: @user4058730 No. You need to differentiate between `Merge` calls, `MergeSort` calls, and number of operations performed.

Answer (score 0):

Not considering the constants does not change the time complexity, it just means that whatever size of input `n` that you give, the constants will not have significant impact on the time complexity. Or in other words, time complexity depends on the size of the input, and constants is independent of the size of the input, therefore it does'nt effect the time complexity..

Answer (score -1):

In Merge Sort we need to sort two entries at each step and merge them. It doesn't care if array is sorted or completely shuffled. Its worst case and best case both are n log(n). Therefore its `Theta(nlog(n))`

Comment: Answer to my question is not theta(nlogn)!!